# Audio stuck in Unbuntu Jelly Jam. Problem resolved

Tags: sound

Found that adding the line
-cache 10000 resolved the isuue of cd audio intermittently pausing.
$ mplayer -cdrom-device /device/sr0
cdda:// -cache 10000

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You can take the [tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) to learn about how this community works and how it is different from other sites you may have visited. Specifically, posts over here are in a question/answer format, with the goal of collecting all information about Ubuntu in the form of questions and answers. While answering your own questions is welcomed, all posts must have a minimum level of detail/explanation. Read [how to ask](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) for more info!